# How to get html to print return value of javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html

What is the preferred syntax to get html to print return value of javascript function?

```
function produceMessage(){
    var msg= 'Hello<br />';
    return msg;
}
```

EDIT: Yikes, too many answers without me clarifying what I meant.  I know how to do it via the script tag.  However, let's say I wanted to make the message red.  Would I just encase the script tag inside my css like so?

```
<div style="color:red><script>document.write(produceMessage())</script></div>
```

I guess my main question was, should you be using document.write to get the return values to print?

Comment: In what context? Are you printing to the console? Adding it to an existing element? Appending it to the bottom of the page? Physically printing it onto paper?

Comment: is console.log() wat u r luking for?

Comment: Hi Matias, I read your answer after editing mine, thanks!

Comment: @LedZeppeling I believe it answers your edit too :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are some options to do that.

One would be:

`document.write(produceMessage())`

Other would be appending some element in your document this way:

```
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(produceMessage()));
document.body.appendChild(span);
```

Or just:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(produceMessage()));
```

If you're using jQuery, you can do this:

```
$(document.body).append(produceMessage());
```

Comment: After doing some more research, I agree with Matias that creating an element is a better approach than using innerHTML.  However both are great, suggestions.

Comment: Thanks and I'm happy to know you prefer adding nodes, which is the Web standards way of doing things, and, in addition, what ensures cross-browser compatibility in your developments.

Answer (score 14):

It depends what you're going for. I believe the closest thing JS has to print is:

```
document.write( produceMessage() );
```

However, it may be more prudent to place the value inside a span or a div of your choosing like:

```
document.getElementById("mySpanId").innerHTML = produceMessage();
```

Comment: I agree.  the second is a better approach.

Answer (score 4):

if you really wanted to do that you could then do

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(produceMessage())
</script>
```

Wherever in the document you want the message.

Comment: I think I am missing something here. I have my function in the head of the html document, then the document.write statement in the body of the html document. However, when I try to run it I don't get any results. Code posted below: `<html>
<head>
<title>Test Input</title>
<script language ="javascript">
function myFunction()
 {
 var = "Hello World";
 return var;
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script language = "javascript">
document.write(myFunction());
</script>
  
</body>
</html>`

Comment: @JerryC You have the right idea.  The only problem with your code is that you named your variable `var`, which is a [reserved keyword in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords).  If you name your variable something else it works: https://jsfiddle.net/g71wxjhc/.  However, I would encourage you to check out the other answers to this question.  `document.write()` isn't really that useful in practical situations.

Comment: Thank you! Probably painfully (to me anyway) obvious but I am new to JavaScript and getting lost in the details.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("<p>" + Date() + "</p>");
</script>
```

Is a good example.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can tell javascript where to write it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var elem = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    var msg= 'Hello<br />';
    elem.innerHTML = msg;
</script>
```

You can combine this with other functions to have function write content after being evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

you could change the innerHtml on an element

```
function produceMessage(){
    var msg= 'Hello<br />';
     document.getElementById('someElement').innerHTML = msg;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you're looking for something like

```
var targetElement = document.getElementById('idOfTargetElement');
targetElement.innerHTML = produceMessage();
```

provided that this is not something which happens on page load, in which case it should already be there from the start.