# Unable to get value of form field

Tags: javascript

I'm learning javascript and tried my hand at calling functions. Based on the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957917/how-to-get-html-to-print-return-value-of-javascript-function), I tried to use the logic in my test html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function ShowForm()
            {
            var field_value = document.forms["test_form"]["my_name"].value;
            document.write(field_value);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" name="test_form" onsubmit="return ShowForm();" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="my_name" placeholder="Type your name"/>
            <button type="submit">My button</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I found that the html renders correctly, however upon clicking the "My button" button, the page simply reloads without displaying the additional html I expected.

The main different is that I'm trying to use `<button>` for the click/submit action. Is it possible to use a `<button>` and activate the javascript? Or should I just style the `<input>` as a button?

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: there is a "," after `action=""`. I guess the rest of the attributes cannot be read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
 onsubmit="ShowForm();return false"
```

Instead of

```
 onsubmit="return ShowForm();"
```

Adding `return false` will prevent page from reloading, removing `return` from `return ShowForm();` will allow javascript to run `return false` after `ShowForm()`.

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/3budz/)

Comment: That worked :) Could you please elaborate on what `return false` is doing?